# Point subdomain to node express custom route with Nginx Proxy

Tags: express, nginx

I have a domain configured with nginx proxy to route like this:

> mydomain.com -> localhost:3000

But now, I want a particular subdomain, to point to something like this:

> subdomain.mydomain.com -> localhost:3000/mypage

Tried several things but I can't make it work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name subdomain.mydomain.com;

  server_tokens off;
  proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

  location /healthcheck {
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

  # NGINX will reject anything not matching /
  location ~ /(?<section>.+)/ {
    # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
      return 405;
    }

    # Only requests matching the whitelist expectations will
    # get sent to the application server
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/mypage/$section;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/mypage/; ... }`?

Comment: Yep, I made it work with that, I think I forgot the last / when tried this one. Thanks